# Find the length of largest subarray with 0 sum

Tags: python, hashmap

Given an array of integers, find the length of the longest sub-array with sum equals to 0.

```
Examples :

Input: arr[] = {15, -2, 2, -8, 1, 7, 10, 23};
Output: 5
Explanation: The longest sub-array with 
elements summing up-to 0 is {-2, 2, -8, 1, 7}

Input: arr[] = {1, 2, 3}
Output: 0
Explanation:There is no subarray with 0 sum
```

Here is an approach to this problem

**The Efficient approach**

```
hash_map = {} 
  
    max_len = 0
  
    curr_sum = 0
  
    for i in range(len(arr)): 
        curr_sum += arr[i] 
  
        if arr[i] is 0 and max_len is 0: 
            max_len = 1
  
        if curr_sum is 0: 
            max_len = i + 1
        if curr_sum in hash_map: 
            max_len = max(max_len, i - hash_map[curr_sum] ) 
        else: 
  
            # else put this sum in dictionary 
            hash_map[curr_sum] = i 
  
    return max_len
```

But fails for test cases like ,

```
[8, -8, 7, -7, 15, -15] OR
[10, -10, 12, -12, 13, -13]
```

Do you have another approach to this problem ?

Comment: mh, sounds like an np complete problem to me. if that's true then there is no efficient solution.

Comment: @DirkR nah, should only be O(n^2), just loop through each index, and for each loop through the rest of the array looking for the longest sub-sequence that sum to zero.

Comment: do the number have to be consecutive in the array? didn't say so. Edit: Oh, well "sub-array" means probably just that. Sorry.

Comment: sub-arrays maintain order, no?

Comment: @thebjorn nah, should only be O(n), as the shown solution already is.

Comment: You plagiarized that solution (maybe from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-largest-subarray-with-0-sum/)) and it doesn't fail those cases.

Comment: @superbrain O(n^2) since you have two nested for loops over n.

Comment: Lolz. I realized that a little to late :-)  Sorry. Fixed my comment.

Comment: @thebjorn Only if you do have nested loops, which you don't need :-)

Comment: Yes, looking at that algorithm now. It's cute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To spell out the solution from the comment. First create a generator to yield all sub-arrays:

```
def gen_subarrays(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(arr)+1):
            yield arr[i:j]
```

then a function to yield all arrays with a zero sum:

```
def find_zero_sums(sarrays):
    for sa in sarrays:
        if sum(sa) == 0:
            yield sa
```

and then a function to keep track of the longest one:

```
def longest_zero_sum(arr):
    longest = []
    for zs in find_zero_sums(gen_subarrays(arr)):
        if len(zs) > len(longest):
            longest = zs
    return longest
```

output of:

```
print(longest_zero_sum([15, -2, 2, -8, 1, 7, 10, 23]))
print(longest_zero_sum([1,2,3]))
print(longest_zero_sum([8, -8, 7, -7, 15, -15]))
print(longest_zero_sum([10, -10, 12, -12, 13, -13]))
print(longest_zero_sum([1,3,0,4,5]))
```

is

```
[-2, 2, -8, 1, 7]
[]
[8, -8, 7, -7, 15, -15]
[10, -10, 12, -12, 13, -13]
[0]
```

You can get a more efficient solution if you sort the subarray indices on descending lengths. Then the first subarray you find that sums to zero is the longest one:

```
def gen_subarrays(arr):
    indices = [(i,j) for i in range(len(arr)) for j in range(i+1, len(arr)+1)]
    indices.sort(key=lambda (i,j): i-j)  # sort on length (-(j-i))
    for i, j in indices:
        yield arr[i:j]

def longest_zero_sum(arr):
    for sa in gen_subarrays(arr):
        if sum(sa) == 0:
            return sa
    return []
```

the output is the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1,2,-2,4,-4]


def myfun(A):
    maxlen = len(A)
    l = maxlen
    while l >= 1:
        for i in range(l,maxlen+1):
            sub = A[i-l:i]
            print(sub)
            if sum(sub) == 0:
                return sub
        l-=1
    return []

print(myfun(A))
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please provide a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answers provided.